# What are the open source audio/video streaming tools available in a browser ?

Tags: open-source, web, streaming, html5-video

I am building a scalable web based conferencing product that will allow users to interact with each other using a webbrowser. I need to support chat and video calling. What are the best options available to implement this ?

There are a few elements to this question -

Its ok if we need to use an extension download. Is the Google talk voice video plugin free to use by external applications ?

Is it possible to build such an app purely using HTML5 features ?

Which is a better option between Flash and HTML (from a performance perspective)

Kindly share any other ideas that you might have.

Comment: What technology google hangouts are based on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/. It covers many of the basic features and it is Open Source.

HTML5 (webRTC) is not implemented in all browsers and specs are not final. So you won't find any production solution yet, just some prototypes.